# Azure cognitive search Index query for Collection(Edm.ComplexType) with a filter on Edm.int64 field is not working

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

I have Index with below fields:

```
{
"name": "my-docs-index",
"fields": [
    {
        "name": "id",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "facetable": true,
        "key": true,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
        "normalizer": null,
        "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
        "name": "field1",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "facetable": true,
        "key": false,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
        "normalizer": null,
        "synonymMaps": []
    },
    {
        "name": "arrayField",
        "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "objId",
                "type": "Edm.Int64",
                "searchable": false,
                "filterable": true,
                "retrievable": true,
                "sortable": false,
                "facetable": true,
                "key": false,
                "indexAnalyzer": null,
                "searchAnalyzer": null,
                "analyzer": null,
                "normalizer": null,
                "synonymMaps": []
            },
            {
                "name": "code",
                "type": "Edm.String",
                "searchable": true,
                "filterable": true,
                "retrievable": true,
                "sortable": false,
                "facetable": true,
                "key": false,
                "indexAnalyzer": null,
                "searchAnalyzer": null,
                "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
                "normalizer": null,
                "synonymMaps": []
            },
            {
                "name": "otherField",
                "type": "Edm.String",
                "searchable": true,
                "filterable": true,
                "retrievable": true,
                "sortable": false,
                "facetable": true,
                "key": false,
                "indexAnalyzer": null,
                "searchAnalyzer": null,
                "analyzer": "standard.lucene",
                "normalizer": null,
                "synonymMaps": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

When I make a search request having filter for field of int64 type I get error.

Query:

```
https://acss.search.windows.net/indexes/my-docs-index/docs?api-version=2021-04-30-Preview&$filter=(arrayField/any(obj: search.in(obj/objId,'101, 102')))
```

Error:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "",
    "message": "Invalid expression: No function signature for the function with name 'search.in' matches the specified arguments. The function signatures considered are: search.in(Edm.String, Edm.String, Edm.String); search.in(Edm.String, Edm.String).\r\nParameter name: $filter"
}
```

}

Azure documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-search-in-function) states the same that search.in can be done on String type of fields.

workaround to this is to filter with 'eq' & 'or' condition:

```
$filter=(arrayField/any(obj: obj/objId eq 101 OR obj/objId eq 102))
```

If I have 100s of Ids to select, then this does not looks good. Is there any elegant/better way to use search.in for integer fields in index collection?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is around a mismatch between data types. Your objId is defined as Edm.Int64

```
 "type": "Collection(Edm.ComplexType)",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "objId",
                "type": "Edm.Int64",
```

but search.in needs Edm.Strings:

```
search.in(Edm.String, Edm.String, Edm.String);
```

But answering your question, I don't think so. And from my experience, complex types are not as useful as it should be. I always prefer to flat them rather than use complex types

Comment: Even if I flatten the structure, e.g. make objId as Collection(Edm.Int64), Issue is that search.in cant be applied to any non string type of field. What is best alternative to this? Why search.in works for string type fields & not int or other numeric type fields?

Comment: why don't you make it as string?

Comment: I need to keep this ID filed int to keep consistency with table in Database. This application is tightly coupled with few other applications so If i change it's type, then either i need to transform responses to all other systems or use transformed data to push to index.

Comment: well, there's nothing you can do besides using a bunch or objId eq 1 or objId eq 2 or objId eq 3 ...